# Cannot write my pseudocodes in IEEE Access format?

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic, pseudocode, algpseudocode, ieeeaccess

I am trying to write an IEEE Access paper by using the template on their website. But I am having trouble writing my pseudocodes since there is no pseudocode example in their template. When I use ieeeaccess template I got error messages such as:

"Extra \endcsname. \State",

"Undefined control sequence. \doWhile",

"Missing \endcsname inserted. \State".

Also, the result does not look as it should be. For instance, all line numbers are zeros in the pseudocode. Also instead of "input" and "output", I got "require" and "ensure" after compiling the .tex file.

Am I missing some userpackage?(although I have tried many combinations still no results) Can someone please give me an example of ieeeaccess pseudocode along with the required userpackages?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{algorithmicx}
 \algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]    
    \caption{Algorithm 1}\label{Alg-Decap}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require{$(C,S_k)$}
        \Ensure{ HashSession$(1,\underbar r,C)$ or HashSession$(0,\rho,C))$ }
        \State $c\leftarrow$ Decode$(\underbar c)$  
        \State $c.(3f)\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $e\leftarrow $ (Rounded$(c.(3f))$ mod 3) $\in \mathcal{R}/3$
        \State $e.(1/g)\in\mathcal{R}/3$
        \State $r'\leftarrow$ Lift($e.(1/g)$) $\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $h.r'\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $c'\leftarrow$ Round$(h.r')$
        \State  $\underbar c'\leftarrow$ Encode$(c')$
        \State $C'\leftarrow(\underbar c',$ HashConfirm$(\underbar r',\underbar h))$
        \If{$C'==C$}
        \State \textbf{return} HashSession$(1,\underbar r,C)$
        \Else
        \State \textbf{ return} HashSession$(0,\rho,C))$
        \EndIf
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First see if it will compile with the article class, hint it does not. Don't use all the pseudocode packages, they are not compatible with each other. The example compiles under the `article` class when I remove `algorithmic`

Comment: Under `article` I also get a different error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmic already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` which hints that this is a compatability problem between packages

Comment: I believe you shouldn't load `algorithmic`.

Comment: @daleif  I already wrote this paper in article format before, and I used these packages:                                                                                 \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%           It works without any problems with these ones in article format with no errors whatsoever.  I changed the userpackages after I switched to ieeeacces  format since it did not work with these ones? I tried different combinations but could not manage to fix it ?

Comment: @campa Even though I remove the algorithmic it still does not work:(

Comment: @esra but here you are also loading `algorithmic` don't load `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode` at the same time. Note there is an `x` at the end in your comment, there no `x` at the end of `algorithmic`

Comment: @daleif I have just edited the code above can you please try with this one again? It works in the article format with no problems. Now how can I convert this to the IEEE Access format? I want the same result  but I could not manage it :(

Comment: No issues here after I downloaded `ieeeaccess.cls` , used your reviced MWE and inserted the `\EOD ` the new error complains about. I'm using an up to date TeXLive 2020

Comment: @daleif instead of  the statements" input " and "output"  as in the article format, I am getting "require" and "ensure" after the compilation? What did you see after compiling? I am using TexStudio.

Comment: So do I but now you are in a different problem than the one you posted, so you should probably post a different question if you need help in reconfiguring pseudo code

Comment: And BTW TeXStudio is not related to any of this.

Comment: I REALLY wouldn't use [H] in a publication.  [htp] will mostly do the same thing, and saves space if not.  Publications are all about saving space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  I REALLY thank you a lot since I have solved the gap problem between the algorithms with your [htp] advice:)

Comment: @daleif actually in my question above I had mentioned it already: "Also, the result does not look as it should be. For instance, all line numbers are zeros in the pseudocode. Also instead of "input" and "output", I got "require" and "ensure" after compiling the .tex file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not load both `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode`. Since you're using the latter's syntax, drop the former.

If you want **Input** and **Output**, define the infrastructure for them.

Also, don't go in and out of math mode and don't use `\underbar`, but `\underline`.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

% no in and out of math mode!
\newcommand{\Fun}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htp]

\caption{Algorithm 1}\label{Alg-Decap}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Input{$(C,S_k)$}
  \Output{$\Fun{HashSession}(1,\underbar r,C)$ or $\Fun{HashSession}(0,\rho,C))$}
  \State $c\leftarrow \Fun{Decode}(\underbar c)$
  \State $c.(3f)\in\mathcal{R}/q$
  \State $e\leftarrow (\Fun{Rounded}(c.(3f))\bmod 3)\in \mathcal{R}/3$
  \State $e.(1/g)\in\mathcal{R}/3$
  \State $r'\leftarrow \Fun{Lift}(e.(1/g)) \in\mathcal{R}/q$
  \State $h.r'\in\mathcal{R}/q$
  \State $c'\leftarrow \Fun{Round}(h.r')$
  \State $\underline{c}'\leftarrow \Fun{Encode}(c')$
  \State $C'\leftarrow(\underline{c}', \Fun{HashConfirm}(\underline{r}',\underline{h}))$
  \If{$C'==C$}
  \State \textbf{return} $\Fun{HashSession}(1,\underline{r},C)$
  \Else
  \State \textbf{return} $\Fun{HashSession}(0,\rho,C))$
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]